# Which UML Diagram is suitable ? Two object interacting, and one is changing the state of other

Tags: uml

- My requirement : I want to come up with a suitable UML diagram based on the case which is described below. I need to know which UML will best suit this condition.
- The case : Two object A and B in the form of "Application Forms" interacts with each other.Certain event in object A triggers a state change of object B.Both object interacts with each other for a Use Case.

I tried using State Diagram but it fails as here 2 object interact with each other to change the state of one object, whereas State diagram is suitable to depict state change of one object only without showing interaction with another object which is causing state change.

My requirement is to show both interaction and state change together in the same diagram.Is it possible?

Any suggestion on this which UML diagram is suitable for this?

Comment: Better Suited on: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

UML uses two different diagrams for each behavior, one for State ([State Machine Diagram](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/stateMachineDiagram.htm)) and one for Interaction ([could be the communication diagram](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/communicationDiagram.htm) or the [sequence diagram](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm)).

Since the Interface of a class doesn't change when it's state changes (by [applying the State Pattern for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)), the interaction should not really change from the perspective of the caller, sure, internally all kinds of things might be going on, but that should not really matter.

The way I'd model this is to describe which states your objects are in and which scenario will play out. That will result in a few interactions and possibly state changes. Then pick a new scenario, either using the end-state of the previous one as a starting point, or describing a new starting state.

That way each scenario is clearly defined, the interaction diagram shows how the objects interact, and multiple State Diagrams with the active state highlighted can show the changes in state and thus behavior of the different objects.

There is no diagram that gracefully combines both, since one (the state machine) is a static diagram, showing all possible options, while the other describes the interaction.

Sure you could play around with creative naming, as suggested (ObjectA/State) as your different objects in the interaction type diagrams, but it would not result in a very clear picture. What you're trying to describe here is a story, a sequence of events and how those events impact the different states of the objects. So your scenario's are the story on a high level, the communication diagrams the stories on a much more detailed level and the state machine diagram the snapshots of specific situations.

Answer (score 1):

Model your states in the state diagram as such: (Object / ObjectState).

For example:
States (A/uninitialized) , (A/initialized), ...

Should work then.

Comment: Your answer is correct, actually I used it in my own version. But as it stands it is little bit raw. Is there anything you want to add?

Comment: I will give some thoughts to it.

Answer (score 1):

State diagram, sequence diagram, communication diagram and the whole answer by @jessehouwing is fine, but I think there is an easier and more natural way:

**(1)** http://agilemodeling.com/style/activityDiagram.htm, Figure 3. Submitting expenses

[image]

<sub>Note that this is [UML 1.4](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/1.4/) activity diagram. Current UML notation is slightly diferent. Dashed lines represent `Object flow` : Chapter 3.90.2.2 Object flow ...Objects that are input to or output from an action may be shown as object symbols. A 
dashed arrow is drawn from an action state to an output object, and a dashed arrow is drawn from an input object to an action state. The same object may be (and usually is) the output of one action and the input of one or more subsequent actions...</sub>

and **(2)** http://www.uml-diagrams.org/document-management-uml-activity-diagram-example.html

[image]

show an examples of how you can combine object states and `UML activity diagram`. The pictures are activity diagrams and the orange rectangles highlight points where objects with states (the part in [*some state*]) are shown. The purple rectangles show authors who were robbed.

Comment: Ambler's suggestion is actually a very very bad idea. He introduces two non-UML notations (dashed arrows in activity diagram, and the notion of two UML objects representing two states of the same entity) without explaining them, which defeats the purpose of using a standardized notation. If you decide to use shortcuts of this nature, you must annotate your diagram with plenty of text or someone who actually knows UML will at best not understand, or at worst misunderstand completely.

Comment: @Uffe Good point. It turned out that dashed arrows meant object flow back in UML 1.4 (I'm clarifying it in edited answer now). Same sort of diagram was also used in UML Bible, Tom Pender, John Wiley & Sons © 2003, Appendix A: UML 1.4 Notation Guide, Figure A-44. So dashed arrows are out of date today, ok, cosmetic change, but what you mean by problem "two UML objects representing two states of the same entity"?

Comment: Normally You'd stick `Document` on the diagram once, and point all arrows to it, maybe annotating the arrow with a function call. Right now the diagram  has 4 distinct instances of a document, which is not true, in fact, there's only one.

Comment: @jessehouwing it is an activity diagram. Document (or object) flows between activities and it is naturally shown many times, perhaps even always when it leaves one activity and enters another. http://www.uml-diagrams.org/software-licensing-activity-diagram-example.html?context=activity-examples. I'd stick one `Document` as an actor in sequence diagram, but in activity diagrams there are control nodes and object nodes which flow through (http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_01/column3/)