# Is there a standard diagram type with both state and activity?

Tags: uml, diagram, activity-diagram, petri-net, state-diagram

I understand that a UML activity diagram describes an algorithm, so in a sense it's the modern version of a flow chart, while a UML state chart shows all the possible (or interesting) states an object or system can find itself in, and shows all the possible transitions between those states.

I also understand that they are orthogonal models: an arrow connecting two states in a state chart represents an algorithm, or a piece of activity diagram; and some, if not all, arrows between two activities of an activity diagram represent the states the object finds itself in between successive actions.

Is there a standard diagram type (UML or otherwise traditional) that gives distinct shapes to both actions (algorithmic steps, including branching, fork/join, etc.) and states between actions (only those states the designer wishes to give a name to)?

Something like this:

```
begin --> (state: new) --> [action: save] --> (state: saved) --> [action: delete]...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which UML Diagram is suitable ? Two object interacting, and one is changing the state of other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600958/which-uml-diagram-is-suitable-two-object-interacting-and-one-is-changing-the)

Comment: @xmojmr [this example](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/document-management-uml-activity-diagram-example.html) uses standard rounded rectangles for the activities and squared rectangles as object states. So yes, that's a preliminary answer.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not, but StateMachine is type of behavior definition which can be defined using some of structural programming features like Decision (called Choose in state machine) , Fork, Join. You can define behavior (actions if you want) to be executed in several parts of state machine.. during transition, in state entry, during state execution and on state exit. In this case you can combine state flow of your object and indicate behavior execution in one diagram. But, behavior defined for states and transition does not have distinct shapes, it is depicted as text within transition name and state definition. See superstructure document StateMachine section  for more details.

Comment: What if my transitions are composed of several steps, with choices and other actions in between? Do I have to give names to all the intermediary states?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a standard diagram type (UML or otherwise traditional) that
>   gives distinct shapes to both actions (algorithmic steps, including
>   branching, fork/join, etc.) and states between actions (only those
>   states the designer wishes to give a name to)?
>
> Something like this:
>
> begin --> (state: new) --> [action: save] --> (state: saved) -->
>   [action: delete]...

Yes, with [Petri Nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net) you can represent actions using *transition*-nodes and states using *place*-nodes; branching and joining is also supported.
I would recommend reading [Lectures on Petri Nets I: Basic Models](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540653066) (paywalled) if you have access to that.